# Calling a public class in android

Tags: android, class, public

I am not that new to android but I never took the standard route to learning the language so am realizing that there are some gaps in my basic knowledge. I need to create a custom toast that I would like to call from any other activity or fragment but I need to pass the background color, text and an image. Here is my public class:

```
public class ShowToast{

    public ShowToast (View viewParent, Context context, int icon, String text, int color) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_delete_mealplan, (ViewGroup) viewParent.findViewById(R.id.toast_root_error));

        ImageView image = view.findViewById(R.id.toast_image);
        image.setImageResource(icon);
        TextView message = view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        message.setText(text);

        view.setBackgroundColor(color);

        Toast toast = new Toast(context);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(view);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

And here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_toast"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingHorizontal="4dp"
    android:paddingVertical="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/toast_root">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toast_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_shopping_cart"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toast_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Added to Cart: Swipe up to see details"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/toast_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

First of all, is this even the right way to construct the class? And how would I go about calling the method from an activity or fragment? Thanks.

Comment: You can pass just a viewParent or just a context. Why? Because You can call `viewParent.getContext()` too.

Answer (score 0):

No.  THat's a constructor, it creates an instance of a class.  You don't want to create an instance of a class, you want to just call a function.  So you'd create a public static function with that code in it, and call it by calling `ClassName.functionName(param1, param2, param3...)`

Basically a static function is a function that does not need an instance of a class to be called, it can just be called.  You cannot access instance variables/methods in such a function, but you can access other static variables/methods on the same class.

Answer (score 0):

This does not make sense as a class or a constructor.

If you want to make a toast from anywhere in your code, you just need the `Context`.

`Toast.makeText(mContext, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

You could define a static method, but I don't think it would be of use:

```java
public static void toast(Context ctx, String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to you can call the function of the external class.

Here, you have must be built modifier as public. (Public Class).

**1.** `className.funstionName(argument1,argument2,...,argumentn);`

**2.** `ClassName classVariable = new ClassName();` // Memory assigning.

```
classVariable.functionName(argument1,argument2,...,argumentn);
```

In your case, you did pass the object of context class in the constructor and also you wanna call this method from fragment and activity.

By calling from **Activity** :

`ClassName classVariable=new ClassName(view,this,icon,color,text);`

By calling from **Fragment** :

`ClassName classVariable=new ClassName(view,getActivity(),icon,color,text);`